# ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize & json string

Tags: java, encoding, xss, owasp, esapi

When using `ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize` on a json string

Input:

```
{ "key1":"some data b\"h" }
```

Output:

```
{ "key1":"somedata b"h" }
```

The output is no longer a valid json string.

How can I keep the original \” in order to have a valid json string for further processing ?

Answer (score 0):

`ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize` decodes a string using multiple codecs. By default it does something like:

```
DefaultEncoder encoder = new DefaultEncoder(Arrays.asList(
    HTMLEntityCodec.class.getName(),
    PercentCodec.class.getName(),
    JavaScriptCodec.class.getName()
));

encoder.canonicalize(...);
```

The JavaScript codec replaces any occurrence of `\"` with `"`. With JSON data this ends up corrupting the input. You could instead create the instance of `DefaultEncoder` without the `JavaScriptCodec` included, or don't run canonicalize on it at all. It doesn't understand the JSON format, so canonicalization isn't doing anything useful.

To prevent XSS, then you need to be careful with how you're passing the JSON string to the client, and how you're using the contents of it. This includes encoding data when outputting it, and checking anything added to the DOM with innerHTML etc.

Comment: What encoding do I need to use in order to avoid xss encoded attack ?

Comment: @AsaBD It depends on the context, but usually html encoding. See rules 0 and 1 at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: JSON data can be sent via an ajax call though so it may not need additional encoding.

Comment: JSON follows JavaScript syntax rules.  You also are missing the point of the canonicalize call:  detecting mixed  or multiple encoding while providing a string reduced to essentially native Java UTF-16.  Validate the canonicalized form, discard it and continue with the original.

Comment: No, it doesn't. JSON is based on JavaScript object literals, whereas the JavaScript codec is based on JavaScript strings literals. They are different formats. Mixing them up results in the corruption shown in the question.

Comment: The string is already a native Java UTF-16. Mixed encoding is something like `%26lt;`. What problem for stackoverflow was caused by me writing that?

Comment: These are perfectly valid characters and can occur in normal data. Preventing JSON data from containing these characters is like stopping people from writing quotes to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I ended up using canonicalize and then validating the data for xss. if validation was successful returned the original string (before canonicalize) else returned the validated (after canonicalize & without the xss) string